OCR Python - pytesseract
I wrote some code using the pytesseract lib and it is working and getting texts from images, but there are still a lot of errors and there are images that don't even get anything. I have already tested some OCR software and saw that they work. Is there anything to improve the OCR of my code?
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Definir o caminho para o executável tesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

# Função para extrair texto de uma região específica da imagem
def extract_text(image, x, y, width, height):
    # Cortar a região de interesse da imagem
    roi = image[y:y+height, x:x+width]
    # Converter a região de interesse para escala de cinza
    roi_gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Realizar a binarização da imagem
    _, binarized = cv2.threshold(roi_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    # Extrair texto
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(binarized)  
    return text

# Carregar imagem
image = cv2.imread('teste.jpg')  # Substitua 'medidor (1).jpeg' pelo caminho da sua imagem

if image is None:
    print("Erro ao carregar a imagem. Por favor, verifique o caminho da imagem.")
else:
    # Redimensionar a imagem para um tamanho fixo
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (500, 600))

    # Selecionar região da imagem
    x, y, width, height = cv2.selectROI('Selecione a localização para extrair texto', resized_image, fromCenter=False, showCrosshair=True)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Extrair texto da região selecionada
    extracted_text = extract_text(resized_image, x, y, width, height)

    # Exibir texto extraído
    print("Texto extraído:")
    print(extracted_text)

example
I needed this better because I could take photos of locations and wanted to get the code from that location to make reports. I've already tested other OCR software and they worked, but they weren't useful for automating.

pytesseract needs nice images to be able to work. Have you seen binarized for every frame and what it looks like? there is nothing here that makes sure that the text is horizontal, which also helps pytesseract in the identification of characters.
